# I am trying to enable the about us button. I have added the path, I have added router link to the container div of the button. What am I missing?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angularjs, typescript

*First is the path in my app routing module
Then the home component
Next is the app component
Lastly the html for button creation*

**path in the app.routing.module.ts**

```
     {
        path: 'about-us',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        data: { type: '', breadcrumb: '' },
        component: AboutUsComponent,
      },
```

**default constructor and ngOnInit in home.component.ts only router variable in constructor**

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import {Router} from '@angular/router';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-home',
      templateUrl: './home.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss'],
    })
    export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
      constructor(private router : Router) {}

      ngOnInit(): void {}
    }
```

**default imports in app.module.ts only**

```
        import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
        import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    
        import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
        import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
        import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
        import { AboutUsComponent } from './about-us/about-us.component';
        import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
        import { LogoutComponent } from './logout/logout.component';
        import { SocialMediaComponent } from './social-media/social-media.component';
        import { LoggedInHomeComponent } from './logged-in-home/logged-in-home.component';
        import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
    
        @NgModule({
          declarations: [
            AppComponent,
            HomeComponent,
            AboutUsComponent,
            LoginComponent,
            LogoutComponent,
            SocialMediaComponent,
            LoggedInHomeComponent,
            PageNotFoundComponent
          ],
          imports: [
            BrowserModule,
            AppRoutingModule
          ],
          providers: [],
          bootstrap: [AppComponent]
        })
        export class AppModule { }
    
        




 **button creation code home.component.html**



        <div class="about-us">
              <button class="button-box" type="button">
                <a [routerLink]="'about-us'" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">about-us</a>
              </button>
            </div>
```

*My objectives are:

i. Redirect to about us component on click
ii. Open about us component when path is mentioned in url
But neither is working!*

Comment: `[routerLink]="'about-us'"` is bad syntax IIRC. Do `[routerLink]="/about-us"` OR `[routerLink]="['about-us']"`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to import `RouterModule` from `import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';`

Comment: In app.routing.module.ts, RouterModule has been added and exported.

```@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}```

Do I still need to add RouterModule in home.component?

Comment: Yes, import RouterModule inside home component.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have include `RoutingModule` in `AppRoutingModule`. If so try the following code

```
<a [routerLink]="['about-us']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">about-us</a>
```

Comment: I am already using routerLinkActive but that does not seem to work.
On click, only the url to redirect to is displayed in address bar, nothing else changes.

Comment: try `[routerLink]="['/about-us']"`

Answer (score 0):

Have you added `<router-outlet>` in
app.component.html file.
Add only above tag & remove everything else from app.component.html if added

Try this & let me know